# Constructing http headers for Java HTTP server

Tags: java, http, webserver

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP server that handles requests from a browser and returns the appropriate answer. I have implemented the basic connectivity already but I have trouble constructing the return header properly so the browser can display the answer from the server (e.g. getting a .jpg picture from the server and displaying it properly).

I think that the problems I'm experiencing have to do with not constructing the answer header correctly. I have little experience with this and I would appreciate any help.

Below is my HttpHandler class, which processes the request from the browser and return the answer. I think the problem is somewhere in the httpHeaderConstructor method.

```
  package Server;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

    public class HttpHandler {

        public static void httpHandler(BufferedReader clientInput, DataOutputStream serverResponse){ 

            int type_of_method = 0; 

            String path = new String();

            try{

                String tmp = clientInput.readLine(); 
                String tmp2 = new String(tmp);

                tmp.toUpperCase();

                System.out.println("Clients request call:" + tmp);

                if(tmp.startsWith("GET"))
                    type_of_method = 1;

                if(type_of_method == 0){ 
                    try{
                        serverResponse.writeBytes(httpHeaderConstructor(501, 0));
                        serverResponse.close();
                        return;

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("1.Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                int start = 0;
                int end = 0;

                for(int a = 0; a < tmp2.length(); a++){
                    if(tmp2.charAt(a) == ' ' && start != 0){
                        end = a;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(tmp2.charAt(a) == ' ' && start == 0){
                        start = a;
                    }       
                }

                path = tmp2.substring(start + 2, end); 
                System.out.println("Requested file path: " + path);

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("2.Error (bad request Exception): " + e.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("Client requested: " + new File(path).getAbsolutePath());

            sendRequestedFile(path, serverResponse);

        }

        private static void sendRequestedFile(String filePath, DataOutputStream srvResponse){

            FileInputStream requestedFile = null;

            try{

                requestedFile = new FileInputStream(filePath); 
                System.out.println("File found and opened successfully");

            }catch(Exception e){

                try {

                    System.out.println("Could not find file!");
                    srvResponse.writeBytes(httpHeaderConstructor(404, 0));
                    srvResponse.close();

                } catch (Exception err) {
                    System.out.print("Error: Can't send failed response!");
                    System.out.print("Error message: " + err.getMessage());

                }   
            }

            String fileExtension = "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePath); 

            int fileType = 0;

            if(fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase(".jpg") || fileExtension.equals(".jpeg"))
                fileType = 1;

            if(fileExtension.equals(".gif"))
                fileType = 2;

            if(fileExtension.equals(".zip"))
                fileType = 3;   

            try {
                srvResponse.writeBytes(httpHeaderConstructor(200, fileType));
                srvResponse.close();
                requestedFile.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        private static String httpHeaderConstructor(int returnCode, int typeOfFile){ 

            String s = "HTTP/1.0"; 

            switch (returnCode) { 
            case 200:
                s += "200 OK";
                break;

            case 400:
                s += "400 Bad Request";
                break;

            case 403:
                s += "403 Forbidden";
                break;

            case 404:
                s += "404 File not found";
                break;

            case 500:
                s += "500 Internal server error";
                break;

            case 501:
                s += "501 Not implemented";
                break;
            }

            s = s + "\r\n";
            s = s + "Connection: closing...\r\n";
            s = s + "Server: Java HTTP Server v0.1\r\n";


            switch (typeOfFile) {
            case 0:
                break;

            case 1:
                s = s + "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                s = s + "Content-Type: image/gif\r\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                s = s + "Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed\r\n";
                break;
            default:
                s = s + "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
                break;
            }

            s = s + "\r\n";

            System.out.println("The returning header is: " + s);

            return s;

        }
    }
```

---

This is the header the program is constructing:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Connection: close
Server: Java HTTP Server v0.1
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

These are the HTML tags that appear in the browser:

```
<html>

    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://localhost:6565/Moon.jpg" alt="The image “http://localhost:6565/Moon.jpg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."></img>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is what happens when you try to get a .jpeg image.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider this sample response header from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 131
Connection: close
```

Second, change your function `httpHeaderConstructor`

```
 private static String httpHeaderConstructor(
    int returnCode, int typeOfFile) {
  // You should use a StringBuilder.
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("HTTP/1.0 "); // <--
                                                     // Missed
                                                     // space.
  switch (returnCode) {
  case 200:
    sb.append("200 OK");
    break;
  case 400:
    sb.append("400 Bad Request");
    break;
  case 403:
    sb.append("403 Forbidden");
    break;
  case 404:
    sb.append("404 File not found");
    break;
  case 500:
    sb.append("500 Internal server error");
    break;
  case 501:
    sb.append("501 Not implemented");
    break;
  }

  sb.append("\r\n");
  sb.append("Connection: close\r\n"); // <-- Not closing
  sb.append("Server: Java HTTP Server v0.1\r\n");

  switch (typeOfFile) {
  // case 0: // <-- Not a good idea.
  //  break;
  case 1:
    sb.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n");
    break;
  case 2:
    sb.append("Content-Type: image/gif\r\n");
    break;
  case 3:
    sb.append(
        "Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed\r\n");
    break;
  default:
    sb.append("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
    break;
  }

  sb.append("\r\n");
  System.out.println("The returning header is: " + sb.toString());
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: In this example is no point to use StringBuilder or StringBuffer. Compiler do it for you. May be in future compiler do more optimisations.

Comment: @AntonBessonov All of the concatenations will be performed with either a StringBuilder or a StringBuffer instance, but it will create multiple instances (and many new intern'd String(s)) for no purpose.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested and the header now matches the example. But I can't still get the response to be displayed properly. I also noticed there is a content length tag, how I am supposed to use it?

The header and everything:

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Connection: close
Server: Java HTTP Server v0.1
Content-Type: image/gif

Comment: @Aris Content-Length isn't required with "HTTP/1.0"; but it's the entire length of the body (after the headers). In what way is the response not displayed properly?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, for example I try retrieving a .gif image from the server's directory. What I get as a response at the browser is "The image “http://localhost:6565/alien.gif” cannot be displayed because it contains errors". This is strange since all the HTML tags are generated correctly.

If i try to get a simple hmtl file I get nothing.

Comment: @Aris Please edit your question to trace your program flow and show the headers... What HTML tags are generated correctly? And if you can't get a HTML file, in what way do you know?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I have posted the output of the program below